Where to extract tar.xz files?
I extracted files of portable program and I want to organize it somehow. Is there a location like "program files" in windows where I can store all apps? How do I add it to apps menu in Ubuntu 24?

Is there a location like "program files" in windows where I can store all apps? There are such locations for apps installed from the official repositories. But fir apps outside the official repositories, you are on your won. You can use /opt, but in this case, I advise you to save it in .local/bin in your home folder.How do I add it to apps menu in Ubuntu 24?  Create a desktop file, and save it in /home/your-username/.local/share/applications  and mark it as executable https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/

This question is similar to: Linking portable installation of a program to Applications. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, there is no such location for programs you download via a browser, but you can easily create one (open a terminal, go to the desired place and type "mkdir chosen_name").
I would advise you to keep such programs separated from the ones which come via packages, or you might have permission issues and you don't want to have to run your new programs as root.

The standard location is /usr/local and various directories there. Why do you say there is none? See https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html
